# Liferay 6.2 kaleo-web portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I would like to know if anyone has ever extended kaleo-web portlet of Liferay in order to modify a file like single-approver-definition.xml. How is this possible using an IDE like eclipse since kaleo-web is located on first level of webapps directory.

Comment: Why do you want to modify kaleo-web plugin in order to change the process definition (*single-approver-definition.xml*)?

Comment: Yes, as I have seen so far the best solution if you want to change the workflow definition is to add a new one using the control panel interface. But I would like to know generally how to extend kaleo-web portlet.